# Is “ ’s ” ever correct for pluralization?

Tags: grammatical-number, punctuation, apostrophe

A relatively modern dictionary (I don’t know which one, because we’ve cut out the pages and used them as wallpaper in our bathroom, but I know it’s less than 20 years old) indicates that *R’s* is one correct pluralization of *R*, as is *Rs*, but whichever dictionary this is, it’s kind of a no-name brand, so I’m not sure I trust it.

I’ve always wondered what the best way was to pluralize single letters or numerals, like *2’s* or *2s*.  What’s correct?

Comment: It is essentially a question of style. Where a style guide is applicable follow it diligently. Else follow your fancy. Both are acceptable in general formal use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plurals of acronyms, letters, numbers — use an apostrophe or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55970/plurals-of-acronyms-letters-numbers-use-an-apostrophe-or-not)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Use_in_forming_certain_plurals):

> - It is generally acceptable to use apostrophes to show plurals of single
>     lower-case letters, such as *be sure to
>     dot your i's and cross your t's*. Some
>     style guides would prefer to use a
>     change of font: *dot your* i*s and cross
>     your* t*s*. Upper case
>     letters need no apostrophe *(I got
>     three As in my exams)* except when
>     there is a risk of misreading, such as
>     at the start of a sentence: *A's are
>     the highest marks achievable in these
>     exams.*
> - For groups of years, the apostrophe at the end cannot be regarded as
>     necessary, since there is no
>     possibility of misreading. For this
>     reason, most authorities prefer *1960s*
>     to *1960's* (although the latter is
>     noted by at least one source as
>     acceptable in American usage), and
>     *90s* or *'90s* to *90's* or *'90's*.
> - The apostrophe is sometimes used in forming the plural of numbers (for
>     example, *1000's of years*); however, as
>     with groups of years, it is
>     unnecessary: there is no possibility
>     of misreading. Most sources are
>     against this usage.
> - The apostrophe is often used in plurals of symbols. Again, since there
>     can be no misreading, this is often
>     regarded as incorrect. *That page
>     has too many &s and #s on it.*
> - Finally, a few sources accept its use in an alternative spelling of the
>     plurals of a very few short words,
>     such as *do*, *ex*, *yes*, *no*, which become
>     *do's*, *ex's*, etc. In each case,
>     *dos*, *exes*, *yeses* (or *yesses*) and *noes*
>     would be preferred by most
>     authorities. Nevertheless, many
>     writers are still inclined to use such
>     an apostrophe when the word is thought
>     to look awkward or unusual without
>     one.

Comment: heh funny, to me "1960's" makes much more sense. i think I interpret it as "the times of 1960" or "1960's", like a possessive. also "nos" and "dos" just looks strange. "no's" and "do's" much better IMO.

Comment: With regard to the last point, what would be the correct plural if one wished to use quotes to delineate the thing being made plural (e.g. did his speech contain seven "You know"s, or seven "You know"'s)?  The latter seems much better visually, since having a quotation mark with letters on either side looks very odd, but I'm not sure which is orthographically preferable if one can't use typography as an indicator.

Comment: @Claudiu: I agree with you about the 1960's.  Among other things, the 1960's consisted of 1960, 1961, 1962, etc. and not just repetitions of 1960. I'm perhaps more inclined to use apostrophes than some pedants, because believe the most important rule should be that that when a mark makes things easier to read, its use is likely appropriate, regardless of what any "rules" say. I would suggest that an apostrophe is often appropriate to separate text which should be read with different levels of "indirection". For example, I would pluralize "ATM" as "ATM's", since such usage helps make clear...

Comment: ...that the things to the left of the apostrophe should be read differently from those to the right.  I would regard such usage as being similar conceptually to the hyphen in the verb "re-cover" meaning "to cover again", except that a hyphen would generally imply a syllable break, but the "read as letters" and "read conventionally" parts of "ATM's" and "DQ'ed" should not have a syllable break between them.

Comment: Another area where apostrophe-s may do a better job of signaling a plural form than s by itself is in product names that have inventory-number-like model names. For example, the plural form of the Apple iPhone 5s is arguably clearer as _iPhone 5s's_ than as _iPhone 5ss_.

Comment: @supercat There comes a point where it's clearer to rephrase.  His speech contained seven occurrences of the phrase, "You know."  Or, His speech contained the phrase, "You know" seven times.

Comment: @supercat The reason for the rules is so that we can communicate clearly and accurately.  If you're creating art, you make your own rules, and your level of concern about whether people understand is probably inversely proportional to the level of pretentious disdain you have for your audience.  If you're a normal person trying to communicate through written language, where there are only words to communicate your thoughts, then your concern is that your audience accurately understands your thoughts.  Thus you need a common language.  Without rules, there is no common language.

Comment: @Xalorous: Some time back, I saw a sign which said TVS in allcaps and it took me a few seconds to recognize that as the plural for TV (normally, when I encounter TVS in all caps, it means Transient Voltage Suppressor).  If lowercase were available, TVs would have been much clearer, but if lowercase weren't available I'd have recognized TV'S more easily than TVS.  Something which is "ungrammatical" but can be readily understood is better than something which obeys the rules of grammar but will cause a reader's first attempts at parsing to go awry.

Comment: The rules for acronyms allow the apostrophe for plurals.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a hair space (U+200A in Unicode) instead of an apostrophe. For example:

**With apostrophe**
The do’s and don’t’s of the 1960’s. Be sure to dot your i’s and cross your t’s. 22 has two 2’s.

**With no extra space**
The dos and don'ts of the 1960s. Be sure to dot your is and cross your ts. 22 has two 2s.

**With hair space**
The do s and don't s of the 1960 s. Be sure to dot your i s and cross your t s. 22 has two 2 s.

**With hair space and italics**
The *do* s and *don't* s of the 1960 s. Be sure to dot your *i* s and cross your *t* s. 22 has two 2 s.

Comment: I like the hairspace with the number, and the italics for the pluralized words, but quality typography is not available in all contexts where one uses text.

Comment: You're talking about typesetting, not written language.  But if we were discussing the four typeset options you list, I'd still pick the apostrophe, since it's the easiest comprehended.