# Adverbial form for a common swear word

Tags: adverbs, apostrophe, is-it-a-word

Is *shittly* a word (and if so, how many *t*’s does it have?) or do I have to use *shittily*?

Comment: One question at a time please, but [check here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/is-s-ever-correct-for-pluralization) for your answer.

Comment: @KitFox that link does not look right

Comment: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shittily

Comment: @mplungian That link is in reference to an additional question OP posted that I removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Shit* (noun)

*Shitty* (adjective)

Generally, to make an *adverb* from an adjective like *shitty*, you change the -y to an -i and add -ly.

E.g.: prettily, cattily (bitchily), dottily (eccentric), grittily, knobbily, shabbily, etc.

Yes, it is a word.

[shittily](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shittily) (ˈʃɪtɪlɪ) adverb (informal, rude): in a bad way; very badly

[FYI](http://www.etymonline.com/baloney.php):  The word *shit* has a long and well-documented history. Anglo-Saxon leechdom books use *scittan* in reference to cattle having diarrhea. A Latin text from 1118 refers to "Lues animalium, quæ Anglice Scitta vocatur, Latine autem fluxus interaneorum dici potest." *

There are many examples of the verb from the 14th century [e.g., from 1387: "þey wolde ... make hem a pitte ... whan þey wolde schite ...; and whanne þey hadde i-schete þey wolde fille þe pitte agen." translated into ME: "they would... make them(selves) a pit...when (? where) they would shit; and when they had stat, they would fill the pit again."]

The noun is attested from the 16th century, both in reference to excrement and to contemptible people.

*roughly: Pay of animals, which in English is called Scitta, in Latin, however, one can say "the flow of her insides".

Comment: Oh those crazy Anglo-Saxons and their four letter words!  Why say something succinctly when you can add extra syllables to make a word like defecate when you just want to shit. ;-)  I am, personally, a one man crusade to take back four letter words!!  (Or so I've been told by thinner skinned individuals around me!)