# How to refer to a collection of paintings by a particular artist?

Tags: possessives

For example, suppose that in an art museum a tour guide wants to refer to a room that displays paintings from Pablo Picasso, so he says,

"This room has the Picasso's."

Would this be correct? Or should it be,

"This room has the Picassos."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is “ ’s ” ever correct for pluralization?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/is-s-ever-correct-for-pluralization)

Comment: But in *speech* you would never hear the apostrophe! The OP writes: *"...a tour guide wants to refer to a room that displays paintings from Pablo Picasso, so **he says**..."* Has no one picked up on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A painting by Pablo Picasso can be referred to as a Picasso, but the plural would be ***[Picassos](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2006/05/29/wanna-buy-a-picasso)***:

> "Russians have money,” he went on. “Art dealers from all over world are
>   now asking me to buy ***Picassos***, other Impressionists. I prefer
>   Renaissance, Caravaggio. But I do not buy them. I’d rather invest in
>   my freedom, rather than in my walls."

*Picasso's* is the possessive:

> *Pablo Picasso's paintings are sometimes called Picassos*.

*Picasso's* would also be the possessive of the painting:

> *The Picasso's texture confirmed its authenticity.*

www.newyorker.com

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "a collection of painting by a particular artist" and considering also different contexts with respect to the one you are referring to I would add:

A [solo show](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solo_show_(art_exhibition))  or solo exhibition:

> - an exhibition of the work of only one artist.
>     The artwork may be paintings, drawings, etchings, collage, sculpture, or photography. The creator of any artistic technique may be the subject of a solo show. Other skills and crafts have similar types of shows for the creators. Having solo shows of one's artwork marks the achievement of success and usually is accompanied by receptions and a great deal of publicity.

or a **retrospective**

> - The show may be of current work being produced, those from a single time period, or representative work from different periods in the career of the artist, the later is termed a retrospective.

- [MOMA](https://www.moma.org/momaorg/shared/pdfs/docs/press_archives/5820/releases/MOMA_1980_0023_25.pdf?2010) sends works from its permanent collection to other museums during the course of PABLO PICASSO: A RETROSPECTIVE.

(Wikipedia)