# What does 's mean at the end of someone's name?

Tags: contractions, disambiguities

I understand `'s` means `is` and `has`, if `'s` is used at the end of a name, Does it mean is or has?Let's suppose Ex is a someone's name.

> Ex is object -it can mean Ex is an object, totally incorrect
>
> Ex has object -incorrect grammar and it does not refer to have something

What does 's really mean? What is the no-contraction mode of name_of_a_person's?

Comment: *-'s* forms the possessive: i.e. *John's car* might be rephrased as *the car of John* or *the car belonging to John*.

Answer (score 1):

When it's not a contraction it's about possession.  But it's really not that simple.  Here's a source that attempts to explain all the cases.

> Apostrophes with Names Ending in s, ch, or z
> Are you confused about how to show the plural and the possessive of certain names? Maybe you know to write I met the Smiths, I drove Brenda Smith’s Ferrari, and I visited the Smiths’ house. But what if the name is Sanchez or Church or Williams?
>
> Rule: To show the plural of a name that ends with a ch, s, or z sound, add es. If a name ends in ch, but is pronounced with a hard k sound, its plural will require s, rather than es.
>
> Examples:
> The Sanchezes will be over soon.
> The Thomases moved away.
> The Churches have arrived but the Bohmbachs are running late.
>
> Rule: To show singular possession of a name ending in ch, add ’s on the end of the name.
>
> Example:
> Harry Birch’s house
>
> Rule: To show singular possession of a name ending in s or z, some writers add just an apostrophe. Others also add another s. See Rules 1b and 1c of Apostrophes for more discussion.
>
> Examples:
> Bill Williams’ car OR Bill Williams’s car
> Mrs. Sanchez’s children
>
> Rule: To show plural possession of a name ending in s, ch, or z, form the plural first; then immediately use the apostrophe.
>
> Examples:
> the Williamses’ car
> the Birches’ house
> the Sanchezes’ children
>
> [grammarbook](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/apostrophes/apostrophes-with-names-ending-in-s-ch-or-z/)

But it's not even that simple as explained in: [Is “ ’s ” ever correct for pluralization?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/is-s-ever-correct-for-pluralization)

And the name itself can change the way you should show possession, as explained here: [Which singular names ending in “s” form possessives with only a bare apostrophe?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79081/which-singular-names-ending-in-s-form-possessives-with-only-a-bare-apostrophe)