# Klingon's are a fantasy?

Tags: apostrophe, greengrocers-apostrophe

In an unnamed corner of this world-wide-web-thing I had a discussion with someone who appeared to be using an apostrophed plural-s. Unfortunately I have this weird allergy which triggers me to respond whenever I see that...
So someone wrote "**Klingon's are a fantasy**" and I hit him...and then the person tried to convince me this should be read as "**Klingon's existence**" - but obviously this would require "**is** fantasy", not "**are** fantasy".
Now...I am German, and he claims his brothers were teachers, so perhaps I am missing something. Is there any valid reason to write it as he did in proper English? ;-)

**P.S:** I'd like to point out that this is **not** a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5210) - the question is more if there is any justification for the apostrophe other than the obvious & invalid plural...

[image]

Comment: I am not a native speaker but I am 100% sure the plural of _Klingon_ is _Klingons_ ----- _Everything pertaining to Klingons is a nightmare-_ ---- Possessive: _The Klingon's bat'leth was very sharp_ ----
Contraction: _A Klingon's a nightmare_, _two Klingons are worse_

Comment: Thanks for your comment - which made me notice that I left out an important detail. Have rewritten the intro...

Comment: My brother is a badass bass player--doesn't mean I can play bass.

Comment: Obligatory reference: http://www.apostrophe.org.uk/

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for that! Unfortunately I can upvote once only!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is “ ’s ” ever correct for pluralization?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/is-s-ever-correct-for-pluralization)

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate, I think. (see edit...)

Comment: As a native English speaker I have *no* idea what the teachers' brother is trying to explain as a justification for his error.

Comment: Thanks - that makes me feel better! (Actually I replied to him "Thanks - I are nearly convinced now ;-)")

Comment: And they go on to finish with "That's **to-days** English lesson!!" Oh dear.

Comment: I'm still hoping it was an example of ultra-dry humour or satire, but he's not giving much reason that would justify this thought ;-)

Comment: Oh, BTW, best of all: that person's signature is "Those people who think they know everything are a great annoyance to those of us who do." - can you believe it?! :-)

Comment: I think I speak better English than what he does ;) At least that is what a British person told me verbatim :)